# Design a 32x4 memory chip using 32x8 memory chip

Tags: circuit-design

I know how to design memory chips from memory chips with smaller word,but can we design a memory chip using memory chips with larger words? 
Our teacher told us that we can't design a 32x4 memory using 8x8 memory because the word with 8 bits is written as a whole and we can't write a 4 bit word , but than he said that a 32x4 memory can be designed from a 32x8 memory but in that case we have  unused memory. I'm confused.

Comment: Trivial: you just don't use half of it. Making a 32x4 from a single 16x8 requires nibble write strobes. With only byte strobes you have to fall back on read-modify-write. But still not impossible.

Comment: @Oldfart So we can design a 32x4 RAM with 8x8 RAM not using half of the word? What about writing ?We just send the bits to be written in one half of the word ? I can do it like that ,but I don't know why our teacher told us that the word is written with 8 bits and we can't write one with 4 bits.

Comment: Moved comment to answer with extra text.

Answer (score 5):

Going from 32x8 to 32x4 is trivial, you just don't use half of it.

Making a 32x4 from a single 16x8 requires nibble write strobes. With only byte strobes you have to fall back on read-modify-write. But still not impossible!

Your teacher probably is frowning on wasting half the memory. Most school assignments are of the type *"How do I build a AxB memory from CxD type"* and always you find you need **exactly** a whole number of CxD blocks.

By the way: FPGAs often have 36 bits wide memory. Many a design only needs 8/16 or 32 bits and drop the last 4 bits. So practically dropping bits is done very, very regularly.

Comment: So ,I can design a 2K x4 RAM using 16   64x8 memory chip  where half of the word is not used,right?

Comment: No, you need 32 of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no earthly reason why you can't use 2 8x8s as a 32 x 4 as long as your timing can be adjusted. For simplicity, let's talk about using a single 8 x 8 as a 16 x 4 - you should be able to extrapolate. In this case, I'll assume seperate inputs and outputs, with the outputs always enabled. Then the key is in using multiplexers to select data and providing a delayed write pulse. Assuming the write pulse is active low,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWF73J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The new MSB of the address, A3, does double duty - it selects which nibble of memory output will be presented as RAM output, and it selects which latched output will be preserved during a write, the other output being discarded in favor of new data.

The falling edge of the write pulse is inverted and used to grab the current memory output. After enough time for the data to propagate through the latch, selection MUX, and RAM setup time, the delayed write pulse writes a combination of old and new data into RAM.

Well, you never said you wanted something practical.